# Is there a nicer way to get a dotted path as a string?

Tags: c#

Is there a better way to turn a dotted path into a string?

```
//I can do something ugly like
$"{nameof(obj)}.{nameof(obj.RelatedObj)}.{nameof(obj.RelatedObj.Field)}";
```

I am having problems finding a nicer solution to this issue.

Comment: "Nicer" is subjective.  What problem are you ultimately trying to solve because there may be an easier way to do it.  Describe what your _actual_ problem is, not the problem with your proposed solution

Comment: @vc74 you can even made a tuple and `Select(x=>nameof(x))` but is it better? I dont think so.

Comment: Have you tried `obj.RelatedObj.Field.GetType().FullName`?

Comment: What do you expect to get, `obj.RelatedObj.Field`?

Comment: @maccettura My problem is that I need a dotted path as a string and I want to avoid using string literals to minimize the maintenance associated with a field name changing while maximizing the readability of the code. My proposed solution avoids the use of a Literal, but sacrifices readability.

Comment: @MatanShahar Yes. My example wasn't perfect, I should have used a better naming convention

Comment: You could probably write a helper method that you pass obj.RelatedObj.Field to that uses reflection to do what you want.

Comment: @NickHansen What is "RelatedClass" in this instance?  Do you mean to say: `SomeClass.PropertyOfSomeClass.PropertyOfSomeClass`?

Comment: @maccettura More likely a nested class IMO

Comment: @vc74 Ah, yeah you are probably right.  The OP has changed the verbiage a couple times now so I wanted to make sure I was on the same page

Comment: I rolled back the last edit since it invalidated existing answers (including my own ;-)). If you have a different question, please click "Ask Question" again instead of changing your current question.

Comment: @Heinzi I think we have a disagreement on whether my edit created another question or clarified the intent of my initial question.

Comment: @itsme86 that doesn't work for my use case because I am not interested in the FullName of the Type of the Field, I am interested in a string version of the path provided

Comment: @NickHansen: I fully believe that you wanted to clarify the intent of your initial question. The problem is that there are already two answers answering your "original" question (however "wrong" it might have been) which are invalidated by your change. Thus, it's better to ask a new question in that case. "Expression to string" (as asked in your initial question) is, unfortunately, a completely different requirement than "full name of class member" (as it looks like after your edit).

Comment: @NickHansen: However, judging from your last comment, it looks like the first version ("path") was the correct one after all. ;-)

Comment: @Heinzi the first version is not the correct one. I want my end output to be Class.PropertyName.OtherPropertyName without having an instantiated version of Class

Comment: @Heinzi I think that your answer still ends up being correct, that nameof() doesn't support what I am hoping to do.

Comment: @NickHansen: Ah, ok. The way I read your second version (`Class.RelatedClass`) was that the second component is a nested class, not a property. Unfortunately, that makes the problem a bit harder, since the "expression builder workaround" won't work here.

Comment: @Heinzi understandable interpretation of what I said. I just meant that the first property is a Reference, and the final Property belongs to that Type, and not my original Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, `nameof` simply does not support that feature currently.

However, other people already had the same problem and wrote reflection methods for that purpose. Here is an example from a liberally licensed project on github (found through this related [C# feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/701)).

Usage:

```
// yields the string "myVariable.MyList[i].MyProperty"
ExpressionHelper.GetText(() => myVariable.MyList[i].MyProperty);
```

Source:

- https://github.com/jjvanzon/JJ.Framework/blob/master/Framework/Reflection/ExpressionHelper.cs
- https://github.com/jjvanzon/JJ.Framework/blob/master/Framework/Reflection/ExpressionToTextTranslator.cs

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it from with expression:

```
public string NameOf<TTarget, TProperty>(TTarget dontcare, Expression<Func<TTarget, TProperty>> propertySelector)
{
    var name = propertySelector.Parameters.Single().Name;

    var expression = propertySelector.ToString();
    // remove 'x => '
    expression = Regex.Replace(expression, Regex.Escape(name) + " => ", "");
    // replace 'x.' with '@'
    expression = Regex.Replace(expression, Regex.Escape(name) + @"\.", "");

    return expression;
}
public string NameOf<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertySelector)
{
    var expression = propertySelector.ToString();
    // remove '() => '
    expression = Regex.Replace(expression, @"\(\) => ", "");
    // replace 'value(...)' with '@'
    expression = Regex.Replace(expression, @"value\([^\)]+\).", "");

    return expression;
}
```

Usage:

```
var context = new Context();

NameOf(context, x => x.Inner.Inner.Value).Dump(); // Inner.Inner.Value
NameOf(() => context.Inner.Inner.Value).Dump(); // context.Inner.Inner.Value

public class Context
{
    public Context Inner => this;
    public int Value => 1;
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I want to do, but I don't have an instance of Context when executing the block, and would want it to calculate at compile time (like nameof()) instead of on execution

Comment: You don't need to, you can replace it with: `var context = default(Context)`.